# how to read httpWebRequest's request stream in c#, i got error" the stream is not readable"?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I want to read the request stream from a custom `HttpWebRequest` class that inherits from `HttpWebRequest` and I have tried to read the request stream in different stages but still not sure how to achieve that in the class.

This custom `HttpWebRequest` is used to serialize a soap message and I want to know what request has been sent in string format. I also implemented custom `HttpRequestCreator`, `HttpWebResponse` but still can't find a place/stage from which I can read the request stream.

If i output everything in a `MemoryStream` then copy the content to request stream, anyone knows  which stage I can do it? In the constructor, `BeginGetRequestStream`, `EndGetRequestStream` or `GetRequestStream`?

Comment: Please clarify your question if you want to avoid downvotes. Also if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: Please post your code, without that it is difficult to say what is going on.

Answer (score 13):

The "stream is not readable"  will result if there is an error return code, like 404, 503, 401, and so on.   It's likely you haven't checked your status code.

Something like this works if the content is text:

```
public string DownloadString(string uri, out int status)
{
    string result= null;
    status = 0;
    HttpWebResponse response= null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        // augment the request here: headers (Referer, User-Agent, etc)
        //     CookieContainer, Accept, etc.
        response= (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        status = (int) response.StatusCode;
    }
    catch (WebException wexc1)
    {
        // any statusCode other than 200 gets caught here
        if(wexc1.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            // can also get the decription: 
            //  ((HttpWebResponse)wexc1.Response).StatusDescription;
            status = (int) ((HttpWebResponse)wexc1.Response).StatusCode;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response!= null)
            response.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The question is about the request stream, not the response one.

Answer (score 11):

Your question is unclear.

If you're trying to read an `HttpWebRequest`'s *request* stream after other code has written to the stream (a POST request), it's not possible.   (The stream is sent directly to the server and is not stored in memory)

Instead, you'll need to expose your own MemoryStream, then write it to the HttpWebRequest's request stream wen you're ready to send the request.

Comment: thanks very much for the response, could u let me know which stage/method i can expose my memorystream ? thanks again

Answer (score -5):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/Blockquote).  Worked for me.

Fiddler:

- is a Web Debugging Proxy
- logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet
- allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with data
- is freeware
- can debug traffic from all almost all apps (web browsers and more)

Comment: that has nothing to do with this. This is a request in an ASP page (or just c#) to an external URL with the intention of using the data in the original request in your application. Even if that were not the case, I'm not going to but a proxy on my production server.